# Bubblesort ignores last element

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to sort an array of pointers, depending on the strings they are pointing to. My implementation of bubblesort seems to ignore the last element i pass on to it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char **a,char **b);
int main(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr[1000]; //build an array of 1000 pointers
    short ptrpos = 0; //start at 0th pointer
    char input[500]; 
    printf("Enter strings(names), seperate by newline\nEOF(Ctrl-D) finishes the input process.\n");
    while(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin))
    {
        ptr[ptrpos] = malloc(strlen(input)+1); 
        strcpy(ptr[ptrpos],input); 
        ptrpos++; 
    }
    short length = ptrpos-1;

//BEGIN BUBBLE SORT
    for(short h = 1; h < length; h++)
    {
        for(short i = 0;i < length - h; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(ptr[i],ptr[i+1]) > 0) 
                swap(&ptr[i],&ptr[i+1]); 
        }
    }
//END BUBBLE SORT
    printf("\n----- Sorted List -----\n");
    for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos <= length;ptrpos++)
        printf("%s",ptr[ptrpos]);

    return 0;
}
void swap(char **a,char **b) //swaps adresses of passed pointers
{
    char *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
Enter strings(names), seperate by newline
EOF(Ctrl-D) finishes the input process.
Echo
Charlie
Foxtrot
Alpha
Golf
Bravo
Delta

----- Sorted List -----
Alpha
Bravo
Charlie
Echo
Foxtrot
Golf
Delta
```

Why is the last string ignored? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Numbers are just examples.*

`ptrpos` starts counting at `0` meaning that if you have 6 elements, `ptrpos` is `6` after the last iteration of your `while` loop. When you calculate length with

```
short length = ptrpos-1;
```

you get `length = 5`.

Your `for`-loops terminate with `counter < length` meaning that they only count to 4 which yields 5 elements not 6.

As the real length of the array is 6, I suggest you change the mentioned line to

```
short length = ptrpos;
```

Now `length` would be equal to the number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 1):

This is what is causing the issue:

```
short length = ptrpos-1;

//BEGIN BUBBLE SORT
for(short h = 1; h < length; h++)
```

Change your loops to

```
for(short h = 1; h <= length; h++)
```

Or change 
`for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos <= length;ptrpos++)` to
`for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos < length;ptrpos++)` 
and, `short length = ptrpos;`

As of now, the loop used for sorting is executing one lesser time than whats required. But, the loop that prints executed the expected number of times by `for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos <= length;ptrpos++)`.

Some more improvements that I'd do:

- Check if `malloc` returned NULL or not, then only do further access.

Comment: The alternate solution `for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos < length;ptrpos++)` and, `short length = ptrpos;` is far superior. Initializing `length` to something that is not the length of the array is confusing and error prone, using the `<=` operator in this loop further adds to the confusion.

Comment: @chqrlie: True, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

here is a working version, 
i commented my modifications

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void swap(char **a,char **b);
int main(void);

int main(void)
{
    char *ptr[1000]; //build an array of 1000 pointers
    short ptrpos = 0; //start at 0th pointer
    char input[500]; 
    printf("Enter strings(names), seperate by newline\nEOF(Ctrl-D) finishes the input process.\n");
    while(fgets(input,sizeof(input),stdin))
    {
        ptr[ptrpos] = malloc(strlen(input)+1); 
        strcpy(ptr[ptrpos],input); 
        ptrpos++; 
    }
    short length = ptrpos; //removed -1

//BEGIN BUBBLE SORT
    for(short h = 1; h < length; h++)
    {
        for(short i = 0;i < length - h; i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(ptr[i],ptr[i+1]) > 0)
                swap(&ptr[i],&ptr[i+1]); 
        }
    }
//END BUBBLE SORT
    printf("\n----- Sorted List -----\n");
    for(ptrpos = 0;ptrpos < length;ptrpos++) // transofrmed <= in <
        printf("%s",ptr[ptrpos]);

    return 0;
}
void swap(char **a,char **b) //swaps adresses of passed pointers
{
    char *temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}
```